# Updating kernel modules in initrd for ubuntu-server usb install

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, installation, usb-flash-drive

I'm wondering how I can update the kernel modules properly in the hd-media initrd file for Ubuntu:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/installer-amd64/current/images/hd-media/

Using those files, I want to make a usb bootable ubuntu server install.
However, to make it work properly, I have to use the old ubuntu 10.04 iso instead of the newer one 10.04.2.
If I put the iso of the latter, I have an error on the kernel modules not being loaded with the installer and my hardware is not recognized properly.

I have trie to replace the modules by modifying the initrd.gz (deleting the old modules in /lib/modules/ and copying newer ones from the initrd.gz on the ISO) but it's not working.
I can't use the initrd.gz on the ISO because it wants a cd-rom and not a usb drive as source.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across your question on google as I was looking to do the same thing. I found this guide helpful: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CustomizeLiveInitrd. I ended up extracting the hd-media initrd and the initrd from my iso and then building a new initrd with the contents of the hd-media-initrd, but replacing the /lib/modules directory with the one from the iso. Here is the script I currently use to build the whole thing: https://gist.github.com/9223336a3a387cfe1eb0